# isPalindrome() function fails on test case

Tags: javascript

Here is a function to detect a palindrome number. It returns `true` if it is a palindrome, `false` it if it is not:

```
var isPalindrome = function(x) {
    const strArr = x.toString().split('');

    for (const [index, value] of strArr.entries()) {
        if (value !== strArr[(strArr.length - 1) - index]) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

};
```

For the test case `1000021`, the function returns `false`, but the expected result is `true`. Is `1000021` actually a palindrome? Why would the test case expect the result to be `true`?

Comment: Maybe it's a typo mistake made by the one who wrote the test case? If you say the function return `false` and it's expected to be `true` so something feels off here

Comment: Shouldn't `return true` be outside of the `for` loop?

Comment: _"Is 1000021 actually a palindrome?"_ Obviously not

Comment: `1000021` isn't a palindrome. Palindrome are words which are spelled equally regardless of if you're reading them from the left to the right or from the right to the left (backwords)

Comment: Your for loop is enumerating and comparing every pair of characters twice.  Do you see what I mean?

Comment: Woops - return true should be outside the for loop! That's why the test case was failing. Also yes, I know it is comparing every pair twice and isn't the most efficient.

Answer (score 0):

`1000021` doesn't seem to be a palindrome.

> palindrome - a word, phrase, or sequence that reads the same backward as forward, e.g., madam or nurses run.

Check with the person who wrote the test case, maybe it was a typo.